# Why are my doublequotes being removed from my command string in my VS Code task definition?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code and I am trying to make a task in tasks.json to set the Git username and email address for the user.

For the task I have:

```
{
        "label": "Set Git User",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "git config --global user.name \"${input:userPrompt}\" ; git config --global user.email \"${input:emailPrompt}\" ",
        "problemMatcher": []
      },
```

For the inputs I have:

```
    "inputs":[
      {
        "id": "userPrompt",
        "description": "Please enter your Git user name.",
        "default": "",
        "type": "promptString",
      },
      {
        "id": "emailPrompt",
        "description": "Please enter your email address.",
        "default": "",
        "type": "promptString",
      }
    ]
```

This seems to be working fine, I get the prompt to enter my name and my email, and a terminal opens up and shows the command just as I expect it. However, after it runs, the user name is set only to the first name given, not the first and last. If I copy the command that VS Code displays and run that in a terminal, it works correctly and set both the first and last name. This just doesn't make any sense to me. If the command were being truncated then the part that sets the email wouldn't be working. If VS Code were ignoring the input after the space then it wouldn't be shown as the command to execute. If git didn't like the space then executing the command in a terminal wouldn't get the desired results. Why is this happening?

I am running VS Code 1.76.1, Windows 10, git version 2.33.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but an extra level of escaping is needed to put a doublequote character in the command string. You need to encode a literal backslash, and then a literal doublequote in the JSON string like so: `\\\"`.

```json
{
    "label": "Set Git User",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "git config --global user.name \\\"${input:userPrompt}\\\" ; git config --global user.email \\\"${input:emailPrompt}\\\" ",
    "problemMatcher": []
},
```

Note that if you switch to using the `args` field, objects in that field can use the `quoting` field to control quoting behaviour.

Related GitHub issue ticket: [\" doesn't work correctly in tasks.json
#31722](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/31722). Also possibly [All double quotes removed from command in tasks.json in powershell
#72039](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/72039).